# Poincaré conjecture (and similar classical problems) in synthetic differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, geometric-topology, synthetic-differential-geometry

I am currently approaching Synthetic Differential Geometry. I was wondering what are the important "classical" problems that can be approached by SDG: for example the Poincaré Conjecture.

More in general, I couldn't find an introductive "list of motivations", i.e. of classical problems that have been approached (or solved) by SDG. Could someone tell me anything about it?

Thank you in advance.